# Passing value to method is always zero

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i have a method in subclass of UIView like this

```
-(void) reDrawPreviewWith:(UIColor *)textColor withGlowColor:(UIColor *)glowColor withGlowIntensity:(float)glowIntensity
```

I am calling this method by

```
float glowIntensity = 30.0f;
[preview reDrawPreviewWith:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]
                             withGlowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]
                         withGlowIntensity:glowIntensity];
```

but inside body of reDrawPreviewWith i am always getting glowIntensity=0

Comment: Did you try to put 30.0f directly into the parameter? It sounds nothing wrong to me

Comment: How do you determine that `glowIntensity` = 0?

Comment: vodkhang: Yes i also tried with 30.0f directly into parameter, its not working

Comment: Hoogenboom: i have checked it via debugging and also using NSLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test your code with a debugger, and it seems to pass the glowIntensity parameter correctly. Are you sure there is no other place where `reDrawPreviewWith:` gets called? Perhaps in a wrong way?